# What is correct? "My whole money" "All my money" or "All of my money"?

Tags: adjectives, idiomatic-language

Recently my English teacher in an example has used

***"I spent my whole money on..."***,

but I thought ***whole*** it's rather used with countable nouns. So I just thought that maybe he made a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is a mistake. You could say "my whole fortune", or "all my money", but not "my whole money".

Comment: You could also say "a whole pile of money" or "i spent a whole lot of money"